# Updating UI component in ADF faces

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, richfaces, oracle-adf

I have a ADF table component which is bounded to a  list  we are getting thorough POJO data control  .The table is also bounded to a managed  bean in viewscope.
My requirement is when ever a new row is added to the db i need my table to get updated automatically .
Scenario is like say  we have two browsers opened by two users .Both of them are seeing same table .If one of the user updates /add one row it should get immediately reflective in another browser .
How can i achieve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not easy. The Normal way would be to use ADS or active data service, but this only works for Oracle Database and ADF Business Components. There is no general update trigger which can be used for this.

What you can do is to poll the data yourself. From the page you use an af:poll component which is a listener which updates the pojo data periodically. However, this is not instant.

Comment: Thanks Timo.Is there a mechanism we can push an event from server to client instead of polling server at regular interval ?

Comment: Actually there its only ADS,  as I mentored  before.  Jdev 12c should offer a server push usable for everybody,  not just  Oracle db.  If I remember right its a feature of the upcoming jsf version.